# Using TAB key for indentation in Python REPL produces strange indentation problems

Tags: indentation, python, repl

I'm using the Python REPL in a comint window via the `run-python` command, and I'm seeing bad behavior when I use the TAB key to do my indentation. For example:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(i)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(i)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Here, the indentation before `print` was created using TAB. I use TAB when editing normal Python buffers, and it inserts 4 spaces in those cases. Here it seems to be inserting an actual TAB *and* it results in an `IndentationError`.

I'd like it if TAB would just insert 4 spaces. I'm sure this is something really simple, but it's eluding me. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This does not reproduce for me. Does it reproduce for you in `emacs -Q`?

Comment: No, it doesn't reproduce with `-Q`. I'm sure (as you've confirmed) that it's something in my config, but I'm too brain-tired right now to make an effective stab at tracking down the right setting. I guess a more concrete question is: What variable - if any - controls what TAB does in the REPL?

Comment: I see... What does `C-h` `k` `TAB` say? It should lead you to `python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent`. That, in turn calls `indent-for-tab-command`, which is part of the regular emacs indentation code.

Comment: `C-h k TAB` is actually bound to `yas-expand`. However, if I run either `python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent` or `indent-for-tab-command` directly to insert the indentation, I still get the odd behavior.

Comment: Try `M-:` `(setq tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode nil)` `RET` in the python buffer.

Comment: That does the trick! Now I just need to add that to a hook associated with the REPL buffer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... Let me make this an answer.

<kbd>TAB</kbd> in a Python REPL triggers `yas-expand` in your case. This in turn calls `python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent`, which calls `indent-for-tab-command`. This is controlled by the regular Emacs indentation variables, which are buffer local. To fix this, you can do the following:

```el
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq
      indent-tabs-mode nil ;; i.e. indent with spaces
      tab-width 4          ;; i.e. tabs consts of 4 spaces
      )))
```

Comment: I was wondering if you'd answer ;) That's exactly the hook I created as well.